# Android AutoCompleteTextView and ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, autocompletetextview

I would use AutoCompleteTextView using data from web-service-rest.The difficulty lies in using a ArrayAdapter with ViewHolder.

this is part of my mainActivity.java

```
final AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            private boolean shouldAutoComplete = false;

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                shouldAutoComplete = true;

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                if(shouldAutoComplete){

                    try {
                        ArrayList<Intervento> interventos = getInterventos(autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString());
                        AutoCompleteAdapter adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.suggest_list,interventos);
                        adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
                        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        });
```

this is my custom class AutoCompleteAdapter

```
    public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Intervento>  implements Filterable {

    static class ViewHolder{
         private TextView  textName;
         private TextView  textId;
    }

    private ArrayList<Intervento> arrayListIntervento;
    private int              layout;


    @Override
      public int getCount() {
        return arrayListIntervento.size();
      }

    @Override
    public Intervento getItem(int index) {
        return arrayListIntervento.get(index);
    }


     @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
         Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {
                    if(results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence arg0) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if(arg0 != null) {
                        try {
                            arrayListIntervento = new InterventoController().execute("http://192.168.1.162:8080/******/******/{*******}/****/**********", arg0.toString()).get();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        // Now assign the values and count to the FilterResults object
                        filterResults.values = arrayListIntervento;
                        filterResults.count = arrayListIntervento.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }
            };
            return myFilter;
     }




    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View contentView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View       view = null;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if(contentView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater =  (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suggest_list, null);

            if (view != null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.textId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idIntervento);
                viewHolder.textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nomeIntervento);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
        }else {
            view = contentView;
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) contentView.getTag();
        }

        if (viewHolder != null) {
            Intervento intervento = arrayListIntervento.get(position);
            if(intervento!=null){
                viewHolder.textId.setText(intervento.getIdintervento().toString());
                viewHolder.textId.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                viewHolder.textName.setText(intervento.getNome());
            }
        }

        return view;

    }

    public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);

        this.arrayListIntervento= new ArrayList<Intervento>();
        this.layout=textViewResourceId;
    }


}
```

and this is my custom layout for listing suggestion

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nomeIntervento"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/autocompleteIntervento" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/idIntervento"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/autocompleteIntervento" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

I can get the data but I do not are shown on the screen. Where is the problem?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you just missed implementing `Filterable`.

Use [this](http://www.sacoskun.com/2008/08/autocompletetextview-with-simpleadapter.html) as your reference.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: There are many nice examples for how to use filterable. just google it. I'm sure you will get one.